# Where is the dockerd (Docker Daemon) in macOS?

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to understand how the Docker Daemon works on my macOS. Can anyone confirm that it's - `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.supervisor` ? How come it's not as simple as finding it in Windows and Linux?

Dockerd paths -

- Windows `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\dockerd.exe`
- Linux `/usr/bin/dockerd`
- macOS  `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.supervisor` - Assumption, need confirmation

Comment: This could be your answer: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27102#issuecomment-251164008

Comment: Thank you for that, a very useful reference, it sure explains a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dockerd process doesn't run on MacOS. It runs in an embedded Linux VM. So you shouldn't find it with the normal Mac tools. Instead what you'll find are apps used to configure and control the VM. For an idea of what's running inside that VM, have a look at the [linuxkit project](https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit/), in particular the [docker-for-mac.yml example](https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit/blob/master/examples/docker-for-mac.yml). However, note that this is only an example and doesn't include the closed source code that makes up Docker Desktop.

To configure the dockerd in Docker for Mac, you can [update the daemon.json file from the UI](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#docker-engine).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your requested information can be useful, but using Activity Monitor you can see that the process `Docker` has a whale logo on the left. This is the main process I believe, and it's under `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/`

---

See the output of `pgrep -lf Docker`

```
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS $ pgrep -lf Docker
959 /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker --autostart
1037 /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.backend -watchdog
1052 /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.supervisor -watchdog
1145 com.docker.hyperkit -A -u -F vms/0/hyperkit.pid -c 4 -m 2048M -s 0:0,hostbridge -s 31,lpc -s 1:0,virtio-vpnkit,path=vpnkit.eth.sock,uuid=06bb4d78-917b-4fe8-a028-2b3bd61d8129 -U 7ac0630a-11d4-4837-8571-9d936ae8f75e -s 2:0,virtio-blk,file:///Users/teixeira/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/Docker.qcow2?sync=os&buffered=1,format=qcow,qcow-config=discard=true;compact_after_unmaps=262144;keep_erased=262144;runtime_asserts=false -s 3,virtio-sock,guest_cid=3,path=vms/0,guest_forwards=2376;1525 -s 4,virtio-rnd -l com1,null,asl,log=vms/0/console-ring -f kexec,/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/linuxkit/kernel,/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/linuxkit/initrd.img,earlyprintk=serial page_poison=1 vsyscall=emulate panic=1 nospec_store_bypass_disable noibrs noibpb no_stf_barrier mitigations=off console=ttyS0 console=ttyS1  vpnkit.connect=connect://2/1999
```

---

The closest thing that offer a listen endpoint customization is the `com.docker.backend` binary, but as @BMitch has pointed, the `daemon.json` file is the way to customize the engine, and you can do it from the docker UI.

Comment: I the Docker process in the activity monitor, but it didn't have an open port. I saw that `com.docker.supervisor` has an open port, mine is 50130, but when I try to curl it via `localhost:50130/info` I get no response. I can only curl via `--unit-socket /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: Never needed to query the service in that way. And why do you need TCP access to it ? Edit your question with the query you are trying to do, please.